# Should I care about Open Session in View when using Grails?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, session, grails

From my experience of using spring MVC in conjunction with hibernate I know about lazy exception problem occured when addressing to lazy-fetched collection when rendering view.
It pure spring+hibernate world it fixes by introducing `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` or `OpenSessionInViewFilter` thus enabling one hibernate session per request.

So the question is: should I care about this problem in grails or such one-session-per-request behaviour is enabled by default.

If this isn't grails defaults please provide some code to implement this behaviour.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grails registers a customized subclass of OpenSessionInViewInterceptor (it adds WebFlow awareness). So anything done in the context of a web request will have an open session and lazy-loaded references and collections will resolve.

Comment: For a view state, when I set a domains instance as a PageScope variable (from taglib) and try to access it in view, why do I get the Lazy initialization exception, could not initialize proxy no error. Isn't the session still open, because the tag is in gsp(layout) which is rendered as part of the view state.

May you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456784/grails-webflow-error-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-when-trying-to-ac

Comment: I'm not sure of the details, but this has to do with Sitemesh and the page rendering order. I think the session gets closed after the controller action runs, but before the GSP is rendered. In general it's best to pass all of the necessary data to the view to avoid this and other issues. By allowing lazy loading to happen in the GSP you're doing database requests from a GSP which is a bad practice in general

Comment: The issue is, I need access to some domain in layout. What would be the right approach in this case ?

Comment: Also, @Burt above setup works very well for normal actions, just flowactions has this issue, so session is surely available when layout is being rendered, but its closed in the case of flow action