# Proper way to handle GORM calls in TagLib

Tags: grails, grails-orm, taglib

I started using Webflow on a Grails 2.2.4 project today and I immediately ran into the following exception:

```
could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Doing some research I ran across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456784/grails-webflow-error-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-when-trying-to-ac) which then led me to [this JIRA issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6701) that is marked as **Won't Fix** because making GORM calls in a TagLib is considered a bad idea.

Since this kind of stuff seems to work fine from regular actions, I've not run across the issue before. My question is, how should the following code be structured so that I'm following the right practice.

I have a template called _nav.gsp which handles my sites navigation bar. There are a lot of menu options that are shown and hidden depending on user's roles. I have the following in a TagLib:

```
def ifProjectGranted = { attr, body ->
    def authenticatedUser = docRegService.authenticatedUser

    if (authenticatedUser) {
      def roles = UserRole.findAllByUser(authenticatedUser).collect { it.role.authority }

      // here I check roles and manage my rendering to the output
    }
}
```

I know I can solve the problem by wrapping my `findAllByUser` in a `withTransaction` block. But according to the JIRA, I shouldn't be doing this lookup at all here. So where would I do it?

Comment: Moving this logic to a `service` and using the injected `service` here in taglib?

Comment: Are you asking me or is this an answer? How would that be different than wrapping this call in a withTransaction? And technically, a lookup shouldn't need to be transactional anyway. Slows things down.

Comment: This is the answer I am asking whether has been tried out. A service class can be made non-transactional if you forecast only non-write operations to be present there. Moving this logic to service class separates the norm of dealing with domain objects in taglib. If you come across more of those cases where you have to access a domain object in taglib as shown in the question, then it is better to rethink about the architectural design.

Comment: moving this to a service class does not solve the issue, transactional or not. I just tried it.

Comment: I am not sure about the behavior with webflow, but an active session will be required to access the domain object. If the logic is moved to `service` class, then there is no stopping to use `withSession` or `withTransaction`.

Comment: I tested it in 2.3.8 and this isn't a problem. However I strongly agree with my comment above afa 2.2.4 is concerned (have not tested in 2.2.4)